# Improper integral $\int^{\pi/2}_0 (\operatorname{csc} x - \frac{1}{x})\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> $\def\cosec{\operatorname{csc}}$
>   Calculate the value of the improper integral
>
> $$\int^{\pi/2}_0\left (\cosec x - \dfrac{1}{x}\right)\,\mathrm dx.$$
>
> You may use the standard integral $\int \cosec x \,\mathrm dx = -\ln|\cosec x + \cot x| + c $.

Please note this is a 3 point question. Here is my solution:

This definite integral is improper at $x=0$, so we have:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{b\to0}\int^{\pi/2}_b\cosec x - \dfrac{1}{x}\,\mathrm dx &= -\ln|\cosec x + \cot x|- \ln|x| \biggr|^{\pi/2}_b\\
&= \lim_{b\to0} -\left(\ln\left|\cosec \frac{\pi}{2} + \cot \frac{\pi}{2}\right|- \ln\left|\frac{\pi}{2}\right| \right) - (-\ln|\cosec b + \cot b|- \ln|b| )
\end{align*}

For $\lim\limits_{b\to0}-(\ln|\cosec b + \cot b|+ \ln|b|)$, using the properties of logarithms, I have $-\lim\limits_{b\to0} \ln|b\cosec b + b\cot b|$.

The limits are both solved similarly by L'Hôpital's rule, giving:

$$-\lim_{b\to0}\ln|b\cosec b + b\cot b| = -\lim_{b\to0}\ln|1 + 1| = -\ln|2|$$

Therefore, I have:

$$\lim_{b\to0} \left(-\ln|1+0|- \ln\left|\frac{\pi}{2}\right| \right) - (-\ln|2| ) = \ln\left|\frac{2}{\pi/2}\right| = \ln\left|\dfrac{4}{\pi}\right|$$

Is this correct and answered sufficiently? Have I made any errors?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is csc? Maybe $1/\sin$?

Comment: It looks fine to me. Just please delete the absolute values for the *positive* arguments of the logarithm: it just makes the reading more cumbersome.

Comment: @Avatar - $cot \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ evaluates to 0

Comment: @Siminore - yes csc is cosec, 1/sin

Comment: @Avatar - No worries!

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

*This CW answer is intended to remove this question from the Unanswered queue.*

---

As [Mhenni Benghorbal remarks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202704/improper-integral-int-pi-2-0-operatornamecsc-x-frac1x-mathrm#comment462211_202704), your answer is entirely correct. Also, the derivation is nicely written out.

Cheers!